# htaccess: add a second rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my .htcaccess file. It redirects the non-www site to the www site. Can I use this same file to do the same for another site, mysite2? How?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No. I already know how to do it for one site. My question is whether I can add a second site to the same file.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you using the same htaccess file for different URLs?

Comment: yes, that's my question. Can I do that?

Comment: Well, all page roots have their own htaccess file, so basically you'll need to create seperate files for every URL you're serving. Lnog answer short: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll add a different file then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a seperate .htacces file for every root URL you're applying rewrite rules to. In other words, you can't do what you're trying.